# Nested v-for; load from Firestore and access changes in each created v-text-field

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Firebase Firestore collection Colours, with each document containing attributes 'alpha', 'bravo', 'gamma', 'delta'. I have a nested v-for loop to create rows of v-text-fields, and this correctly displays the values from Firestore in the textfields upon loading the page.

I want to be able to change the text in the v-text-fields, so that I can click a button to update the values in the corresponding Firestore document.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Using the :ref value doesn't update, when the update() method is called below it just prints the original value that was loaded when the page loaded.

I've tried various v-model combinations, which I believe may be what I need to do, but again I couldn't get this to work. It seemed like this way it wouldn't load the textfields with the Firestore values at the start.

Suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
<v-card v-for="Colour in Colours" :key="Colour.id">
  <v-col v-for="i in Items" :key="i">
    <v-text-field :ref="Colour.id" :value="Colour[i]" :v-model="fields[Colour.id]"></v-text-field>
  </v-col>

  <v-btn @click="update(Colour.id)">Update</v-btn>

</v-card>
```

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      Items: ['alpha', 'bravo', 'gamma', 'delta'],

...
```

```
update(ref) {
  //I won't have any issue with the actual Firestore .update() stuff, but I can't work out how to get the new value of whatever is in the v-text-field.

  console.log(this.$refs[ref][0].value) //this doesn't print an updated value once the text in the v-text-field was changed
}
```

```
firestore: {
  Colours: db.collection("Colours")
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it!

If I just use

```
v-model="Colour[i]"
```

and get rid of `:ref="Colour.id"`

I can then do

```
<v-btn @click="update(Colour)">Update</v-btn>
```

And then the values are correctly updated, and accessible for me in that update() method, e.g.:

```
updateSentence(col) {
  console.log(col.alpha)
  console.log(col.beta)
  console.log(col.gamma)
}
```

I found this answer by pure chance, trying every possibility I could think of. I'm surprised I don't need `:v-model`.